# What causes MATLAB's contourf to hang?

Tags: matlab, contour

I have matlab code that generates an array. I verified that the array doesn't contain any NAN values using `any(isnan(myArray(:)))` as suggested

The array is 1601 by 1021.

I then use the built-in method `contourf(myArray,10)` (Edit: added limit of 10)  on this array (Also results in a problem with `contour`.

The result is for matlab to go to "Busy" and hang for eternity.

I waited several hours just to make sure, the same data plots in about 10 seconds using the surf command.

When I press Ctrl+C to kill the execution I get this:

```
???
Error in ==> specgraph.contourgroup.schema>LdoDirtyAction at 265
refresh(h)

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback.
> In contourf at 78
```

I'm completely at loss on this, so any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Just found out using imagesc(a) that the data is horrendous, like doing a contour map of manhattan island but including the buildings, this may be the cause, I'm investigating now. I didn't know this before because I hadn't been able to visualize the data.

Comment: have you tried limiting the number of contour lines: contourf(myArray,10)? maybe the function is getting lost or taking so long because it generates a lot of contour lines...

Comment: Just a remark: you can use [`isnan()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isnan.html) in combination with [`any()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) to check for `NaN`s in your array. For instance: `any(isnan(myarray(:)))` will return `true` if there is any `NaN` in `myarray`

Comment: I tried contours(myArray,10) with no better luck I'm afraid, `any(isnan(a))` is quicker way to check, there was no NaN though.